# Can't permanently revoke user roles

Tags: 6, users

I run a very large D6 college website (upgrading to D7 isn't feasible right now due to time/budget restraints). I noticed today that a few users have the "admin" role even though they've never been granted it and shouldn't have it. I tried to remove the role from their accounts in three ways:

1. Via user/edit - no effect whatsoever. The role stayed checked.
2. Via VBO - again, no effect at all.
3. By deleting the appropriate roles in the user_roles table. This worked until they logged in, at which point Drupal re-assigns the admin role to them (!!!).

What in the world could be happening here? Most (but not all) of the affected users are members of another role called marcomm.

Server is IIS 8.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only really speculate, there's about a million things that could be happening. What I would do is grab a stacktrace from user_save, which is the most likely location for the roles to be added. Then work your way back to which module is responsible.

Comment: Sounds like a module is 'helpfully' granting the roles for you, needs more information to debug. Stepping through the user_save process would help.

Comment: Welp, now I feel dumb. Thanks for the help; I traced the issue to CiviCRM, which was set up to sync its own "admin" role to the Drupal admin role.